# Why does changing FontStyle, when there is a copy paste from keyboard, cause clipboard to be cleared?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code would highlight the current row and restore the previous row.

```vb
Private Sub mcrToggleHighlightedRow(iPassedPrevRow As Integer, iPassedCurRow As Integer)
     
'2022.05.16 - changing the font.fontstyle was forcing the clipboard to be cleared/deleted.
' Couldn't do any copy and pasting


'remove highlighting on previous row
If iPassedPrevRow <> 0 And iPassedPrevRow >= 16 Then
    'Non fillable rows - Reset
    With Range("A" & iPassedPrevRow & ":C" & iPassedPrevRow)
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
'        .Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
    End With
    With Range("D" & iPassedPrevRow & ":D" & iPassedPrevRow)
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
'       .Font.FontStyle = "Italic"
'       .Font.Size = 8
    End With
    With Range("S" & iPassedPrevRow & ":S" & iPassedPrevRow)
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
'        .Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
    End With
    
    'Yellow Fillable Rows - reset
    With Range("E" & iPassedPrevRow & ":E" & iPassedPrevRow)
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
    End With
    With Range("J" & iPassedPrevRow & ":L" & iPassedPrevRow)
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
    End With
     
End If

'if selected cell is not in the detail lines, exit
If iPassedCurRow < 16 Then Exit Sub

If iPassedCurRow <> 0 Then
    'Non fillable rows
    With Range("A" & iPassedCurRow & ":C" & iPassedCurRow)
        .Interior.Color = 16777164
'        .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    End With
    With Range("D" & iPassedCurRow & ":D" & iPassedCurRow)
        .Interior.Color = 16777164
'        .Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
'        .Font.Size = 12
    End With
    With Range("S" & iPassedCurRow & ":S" & iPassedCurRow)
        .Interior.Color = 16777164
'        .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    End With
    
    'Yellow Fillable Rows
    With Range("E" & iPassedCurRow & ":E" & iPassedCurRow)
      .Interior.Color = 13434879
'      .Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
    End With
    With Range("J" & iPassedCurRow & ":L" & iPassedCurRow)
      .Interior.Color = 13434879
    End With
    
End If
```

Before commenting out the `.Fond.FontStyle` lines, I would CTRL-C to copy and put something in the clipboard, it would be cleared from the clipboard after moving to a new cell, thus not able to CTRL-V and paste it.

Once I commented out the lines, copy and paste works again.

What is causing the clipboard to be cleared?

Comment: Is all the relevant code there? I see no `Copy` or `Paste` in the sample code. Why not format after pasting?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/611854/prevent-excel-from-clearing-copied-data-for-pasting-after-certain-operations-w with suggestions for a workaround (there apparently being no way to stop this behavior).

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad... The copy/paste is from actual keyboard hotkeys.  If I hit copy on a cell then move to another cell, i'm not able to paste due to the code deleting the clipboard.

Comment: @ouroboros1 - thank you for the link(s).  Makes sense and I'm glad to know that it's not something I'm doing wrong.  In the many years of using excel, this is the first that I've come across this.